# Trying to port this code from C# to VB.NET (derives from IHttpExecuteInterceptor)

Tags: c#, vb.net

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69325115/2287576) which has this code in C#:

```
public class GoogleBatchInterceptor : IHttpExecuteInterceptor
{
    public async Task InterceptAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        if (request.Content is not MultipartContent multipartContent)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        foreach (var content in multipartContent)
        {
            content.Headers.Add("Content-ID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to port this to VB.Net and I tried to begin with:

```
Imports Google.Apis.Http.IHttpExecuteInterceptor

Public Class GoogleBatchInterceptor :   IHttpExecuteInterceptor

End Class
```

It says:

> Declaration expected.

How do I port this code over? It is so I can temporarily circumnavigate a Google Calendar API issue

---

### Update

I have got this far now:

```
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Threading
Imports Google.Apis.Http

Public Class GoogleBatchInterceptor
    Implements IHttpExecuteInterceptor

    Private Async Function IHttpExecuteInterceptor_InterceptAsync(request As HttpRequestMessage, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task Implements IHttpExecuteInterceptor.InterceptAsync
        Await Task.CompletedTask
        'If request.Content Is Not MultipartContent multiplepartContent Then
        '    Return
        'End If

        'For Each (dim content)


    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: `Implements` instead of `:`

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Seems like I needed `: Implements`.

Comment: No, you didn't need that. The colon is used in VB to put two separate lines of code on the same physical line. Just don't put them on the same line. Declare the class on one line and then specify the base class and or any implemented interface(s) on subsequent lines.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Understood! So I got that first bit right now with now `:`. And now I hit the brick wall with the `if` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent for the pattern-matching used in that C# code. The closest VB equivalent would be this:

```vb
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Threading
Imports Google.Apis.Http

Public Class GoogleBatchInterceptor
    Implements IHttpExecuteInterceptor

    Public Async Function InterceptAsync(request As HttpRequestMessage, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task Implements IHttpExecuteInterceptor.InterceptAsync
        Await Task.CompletedTask

        Dim multipartContent = TryCast(request.Content, MultipartContent)

        If multipartContent Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        For Each content In multipartContent
            content.Headers.Add("Content-ID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        Next
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: If this is for .NET Framework, I don't think you can make it async; at least in my testing, the VB compiler isn't OK with that even though it ought to be allowable (VS 2019 / .NET Framework 4.8).  It might work with .NET 5.0.  Regardless of whether it can be done, I'd still recommend against it, and just return `Task.CompletedTask` instead of the vacuous await.  (I made the same comment on the C# answer and will submit a proposed edit there as soon as the queue isn't full.)